# Actionscript 3 Score count on hitTestObject

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've been working on this simple car game in Flash CS5. The car has to avoid the cars coming vertically and pick up coins. I have three types of coins which add 1, 2 and 3 score points on being picked up. My problem is that when I hit the coin with the car it goes through the car and gives much more points. I also have problem with removing it from the stage... Here the code so far:

```
var spex:Number = 0;
var spey:Number = 4;
var score:uint;
var cars:Array = new Array  ;
var db:Number = 2;
var db_coins:Number = 1;
var i:Number = 0;
for (i=0; i<=db; i++)
{
    var traffic_mc:MovieClip = new traffic  ;
    cars.push(addChild(traffic_mc));
    cars[i].x = -500 * Math.random();
    cars[i].y = Math.random() * 400;
    trace(cars[i].y);
}

for (i=0; i<=db_coins; i++)
{
    var coin_y:MovieClip = new coin_yellow  ;
    coin_y.x = -500 * Math.random();
    coin_y.y = Math.random() * 400;
    addChild(coin_y);
    var coin_r:MovieClip = new coin_red  ;
    coin_y.x = -500 * Math.random();
    coin_y.y = Math.random() * 400;
    addChild(coin_r);
    var coin_b:MovieClip = new coin_blue  ;
    coin_b.x = -500 * Math.random();
    coin_b.y = Math.random() * 400;
    addChild(coin_b);
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keydown);
function keydown(k:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (k.keyCode == 37)
    {
        spex -=  4;

    }
    if (k.keyCode == 39)
    {
        spex +=  4;
    }
}
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, go);
function go(e:Event):void
{
    this.auto.x +=  spex;
    if (this.auto.x < 25)
    {
        this.auto.x = 25;
        spex = 0;
    }
    if (this.auto.x > 286)
{
    this.auto.x = 286;
    spex = 0;
    }
    for (i=0; i<=db; i++)
    {
        if (cars[i].hitTestObject(this.auto))
        {
            trace("GAME OVER");
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keydown);
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, go);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, retry);
        }
        cars[i].y +=  spey;
        if (cars[i].y > 600)
        {
            cars[i].y = -50;
            cars[i].x = Math.random() * 251;
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<=db_coins; i++)
    {
        if (coin_y.hitTestObject(this.auto))
        {
            score +=  1;
            updateScore();
        }
        coin_y.y +=  spey-2;
        if (coin_y.y > 600)
        {
            coin_y.y = -50;
            coin_y.x = Math.random() * 251;
        }
        if (coin_r.hitTestObject(this.auto))
        {
            score +=  2;
            updateScore();
        }
        coin_r.y +=  spey-2;
        if (coin_r.y > 600)
        {
            coin_r.y = -50;
            coin_r.x = Math.random() * 251;
        }
        if (coin_b.hitTestObject(this.auto))
        {
            score +=  3;
            updateScore();
        }
        coin_b.y +=  spey-2;
        if (coin_b.y > 600)
        {
            coin_b.y = -50;
            coin_b.x = Math.random() * 251;
        }
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, retry);
function retry(k:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (k.keyCode == 32)
    {
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, go);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keydown);
        for (i=0; i<=db; i++)
        {
            cars[i].y = -300 * Math.random();
            cars[i].x = Math.random() * 251;
        }

        for (i=0; i<=db_coins; i++)
        {
            coin_y.y = -300 * Math.random();
            coin_y.x = Math.random() * 251;
            coin_r.y = -300 * Math.random();
            coin_r.x = Math.random() * 251;
            coin_b.y = -300 * Math.random();
            coin_b.x = Math.random() * 251;
        }
        spex = 0;
        spey = 4;
        score = 0;
        scorecounter.text = "Score: " + score.toString();
    }
}

//Scorecount

function init():void
{
    score = 0;
    scorecounter.text = "Score: " + score.toString();
}

function updateScore():void
{
    scorecounter.text = "Score: " + score.toString();
}

init();
```

Comment: Not clear what `db_coins` is, and why you cycle thru it (but never use the iteration variable `i`). Can you attach also a screenshot? Anyway, the solution is to remove a coin from the stage when hit.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should create a variable like hited:Boolean and check first hit. Coin issue occurs cause coin isn't hitting for one time, it is hitting for a while cause every frame you move it and with movement it hits again. So you have to check it and make a proper "if-else" condition.

Comment: That's another good solution... But usually coins in games disappear when picked up :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I've found a solution! :)
simply moving it out from the stage on hit.
coin_y.x=-1000;

Comment: You can use removeChild() to remove the coin sprite display object off the stage, else you may end up 'piling up' coins at x=-1000.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution than the one you decided to use.  spex is the variable that you are using to scroll the game.  When you run your hitTestObject on the car simply put spex = 0;  This will stop the game dead.

I agree with mitim to use removeChild() for the coins instead of just piling them up off stage.